# Is there a way to combine CoreML models?

Tags: swift, coreml

I want to combine the available CoreML models that Apple provides in order to create a large one that is able to identify objects more accurately. Is there a way to either unpack these models, combine them, and repack them, or to use them in an array combining within the Swift code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short: no. This is not how these models work.

You could combine multiple models into one big one, but that's the same as running them individually.

What you *can* do is make predictions using multiple models, then take the average of these predictions, and use that as the final prediction. That's called "ensembling". But it's overkill for use on a mobile device.

Comment: How do you combine multiple models into one big one? I have a pair of orthogonal image classifiers I'd love to be able to run in one VNCoreMLRequest.

Comment: Easiest way: combine them in whatever tool you used for training (TF, PyTorch, Keras), then convert the model again. Slightly harder: put them into a Core ML pipeline (if that makes sense). Hardest: copy the layers from the second model into the first model using coremltools. (I wrote a book about doing this kind of stuff.)